# Position 31:28. MarkupExtension not found for appsNames with xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

hello I am working on a app in xamarin forms that shows a list of all installed apps on the device and you can create a shortcut into my app to quickly launch it. this all works fine the issue I'm having is i'm trying to make a card styled xaml layout and bind the app list to my xaml when I open this part of the app it crashes and gives me this error:

> Position 31:28. MarkupExtension not found for appsNames

EDIT: I tried @Jason suggestion and I still get this error

here's my updated xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AppName.ListInstalledAppsPage">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame  IsClippedToBounds="True"
         HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
                        <Frame.OutlineColor>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                  Android="Gray"
                  iOS="Gray"/>
    </Frame.OutlineColor>

<Frame.Margin>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="10" iOS="10"/>
    </Frame.Margin>

                            <Frame.Padding>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="0" iOS="0"/>
    </Frame.Padding>
                                <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
 <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label 
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           ItemsSource="{appsNames}"
                           FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                           FontSize="24"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

here's my updated code behind:

```
       using AppName.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName
{
    public partial class ListInstalledAppsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListInstalledAppsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var appsNames = new List<String>();
            PackageInterface pkg = DependencyService.Get<PackageInterface>();
            var apps = pkg.GetInstalledApps();
            foreach (var a in apps)
            {
                appsNames.Add(a.Name);
            }


            listView.ItemSelected += async (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
                }
                string app = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Add to?", "Cancel", null, "Home", "Math", "Science", "Handwriting");
                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(action))
                {
                    string appsList = Application.Current.Properties[action] as string;
                    if (!appsList.Contains(app))
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appsList))
                        {
                            appsList = app;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            appsList += ";" + app;
                        }
                        Application.Current.Properties[action] = appsList;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Properties.Add(action, app);
                }
                await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                MessagingCenter.Send<ListInstalledAppsPage>(this, "Refresh");
            };

        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: if you are creating your ListView entirely in the code behind, then why do you even have a XAML page?  Additionally, Label does not have an ItemsSource property, and the binding syntax you are using for Label appears to be completely invalid.

Comment: @Jason the reason I have the xaml page is so that I can use the card style layout witch is not coded in the code behind any idea on how to get this to work? thanks for the fast reply! :)

Comment: don't assign Content in the code behind - that just overwrites everything in your XAML.  Don't create a new ListView in your code behind, instead use a reference to the XAML ListView.  Fix the broken Label.

Comment: @Jason I tried your suggestion and i'm still getting the same error please check updated code and let me know what to try next thanks for all your help so far! :)

Comment: You still have an invalid ItemsSource property on your Label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that in the label you want to show the string from appsNames?

First you need to set the ItemsSource of the ListView to appsNames. You can either do that through binding or your code behind.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding appsNames}" />
```

This is assuming that you set your BindingContext of your page to itself. e.g. In the constructor, add:

```
BindingContext = this;
```

Or next you can assign it in code behind like this:

```
listView.ItemsSource = appsNames;
```

Then this line, in your XAML

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       ItemsSource="{appsNames}"
       FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
       FontSize="24"/>
```

needs to be

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       Text="{Binding .}"
       FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
       FontSize="24"/>
```

The reason you get the error is because appsNames doesn't mean anything in XAML, and also a Label doesn't have an ItemsSource property.